# how do I clear the values in my text input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code doesn't run and I want the value to be cleared when you click on another

what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/AL2vS/

```
var placeholderText = $('input').val();

$(placeholderText).focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', "");
});
$(placeholderText).blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', phTextVal);
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using 'placeholderText' as a selector, which won't select anything. Use `$('input').focus(...` and `$('input').blur(...` instead.

**UPDATE**

If you want to store the existing value, and then replace it, then store it as `.data()` in the `<input>` element itself:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.data('oldval',$this.val());
    $this.val('');
});
$('input').blur(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.data('oldval'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AL2vS/12/

Or possibly:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length==0) { // only if the field is blank
        $this.val($this.data('oldval'));
    };
});​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AL2vS/6/ I did that but now everything shows up as my first value attribute.

Comment: Fixable, but I don't understand why you want to overwrite the user's text as soon as he blurs out of the field.

Comment: I had edited your code but if I wanna keep the original placeholder text I dont know how to do that http://jsfiddle.net/Nz2GH/4/

Comment: @webdevgirl Consider the updated answer, or post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/AL2vS/1/

Answer (score 0):

This will at least get the removal of text working:

```
var placeholderText = $('input');

placeholderText.focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', "");
});
placeholderText.blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', phTextVal);
});​
```

You could also take a look at the HTML5 [placeholder param](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder).

Comment: yes I know the html5 placeholder attribute will do that automatically but I wanted to learn the jQuery way

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better way is:

```
var placeholderText = $('input');

$(placeholderText).focus(function() {
    phTextVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).val(phTextVal);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out,

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    placeholderText = $('input').val();
    $(this).val("");
});

$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).val(placeholderText);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AL2vS/8/

you still need to do something with the data that is entered.

Answer (score 0):

How about using **object.defaultValue** property?

**function:**

```
$.fn.smartInput=function(){
    return this.each(function(i,o){
     $(o).focus(function(){ if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';})
         .blur(function(){ this.value=(this.value=='')?this.defaultValue:this.value;});
     });
```

}

**usage:**

```
$('input').smartInput();
```